# Yet another headphone stuck in retina macbook pro question

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, headphones

as the title states, my headphone jack is useless because a headphone cable broke off in the jack. I can't get audio through the speakers because the computer thinks there're headphones plugged in. I had read and thought that I couldn't redirect audio because it was a hardware issue. But, when I installed Windows 7 through bootcamp, I was getting audio through the speakers. So, I know now that it isn't a hardware issue, but a software issue in OSX.

If one were to solve this via software (hack, script, etc) how do you think one would go about doing this?

Last time I took in my computer to the Apple store to try and get the bit of cable out of the jack, they couldn't and recommended that I use an adhesive.

Thanks for your help

Latest version retina macbook pro 15" (mid or late 2012) running OSX 10.8.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know about software but assume you would like to use your Headphone eventualy.

Removing broken Headset pin

> The gentle methods:

Use instant glue at the end of Q-tip shaft.

The disadvantage, depending how deep you have to go in glue can stick and cover the contacts in the socket so it wont work afterward.

> The "Man" methods:

Use Drill bits (broken screw) [removal tools](http://www.righttoolusa.com/p/Aircraft-Tool-Supply-Pro-Grabit-Broken-Bolt-&-Damaged-Screw-Remover-4-Pc-19172758.html), or something like it.
Yes you will be drilling :)

The disadvantage: You are Drilling !

> The profession methods:

Disassemble you computer and access the headphone jack from inside>this is the best method.

The disadvantage: Know-how + Time + Cost! ?

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for a software fix, but can't help it if one doesn't exist.

I'll be taking it to a different apple store hopefully with better results.

Thanks again.